# Who is the King of Babylon referenced in Isaiah 14:4 and 14:17?

Tags: history, isaiah, referent-identification

> [Isa 14:4, 17 NLT] (4) you will taunt the king of Babylon. You will say, "The mighty man has been destroyed. Yes, your insolence is ended. ... (17) Is this the one who destroyed the world and made it into a wasteland? Is this the king who demolished the world's greatest cities and had no mercy on his prisoners?'

Comment: Actually some scholars believe that Isaiah is not talking about a Babylonian king but rather about an Assyrian king (more specifically Sargon II) who happened to have ruled in Babylon, who died in war and never got  proper burial. This would fit the context better, although there is no escaping the fact that chapter 13 is clearly about the Babylonian empire, as v. 17 makes abundantly clear. You can see more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_14

Comment: Isaiah 13 is clearly a later insertion, since Isaiah is talking about the mighty Babylonian empire and the land of the Chaldeans and the Median empire, empires which didn't exist yet in Isaiah's days and clearly weren't mighty in his time. The big threat in Isaiah's days was the mighty Assyrian empire. That's why I think 14 would fit the context better if it were talking about Sargon, but chapter 13 remains misplaced.

Comment: Hi Bach. I always am glad to see your comments and answers because they are meaty. Thanks for posting. @Dottard suggests that "either/or" might not be necessary as the king seems to be an amalgam. Does that resonate with you? There seemed to be a confusion of referents, which is why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: not really, v. 18-20 clearly seem to address a specific king that didn't get a proper burial.

Comment: Yes, a lot fits Sargon II very well, especially *[Isa 14:25 NLT] (25) I will break the Assyrians when they are in Israel; I will trample them on my mountains. My people will no longer be their slaves nor bow down under their heavy loads.* Others, no, such as *[Isa 14:22-23 NLT] (22) This is what the LORD of Heaven's Armies says: "I, myself, have risen against Babylon! I will destroy its children and its children's children," says the LORD. (23) "I will make Babylon a desolate place of owls, filled with swamps and marshes. I will sweep the land with the broom of destruction. ..."*

Comment: @Bach, if you create an answer suggesting Sargon II, I will give it at least an upvote. So far, it appears to me that the king is an amalgam, including Sargon II and an anachronistic reference to Babel. Oh and Nabonidius most importantly! But really, it seems to be a mess!

Comment: My colleague actually suggested that instead of Media in Isaiah 13:17 it originally said Assyria. That would mean that this prophecy indeed was initially intended for babylonia, i.e., Assyria will attack babylon and decimate it. It was later changed to Media to make it fit the actual events. This would actually explain how 13 made it in there. Is all part of the greater plan God has for the world thru the mighty Assyrian empire, as is evident from the following chapters until Isaiah 40. Its all focused on Assyria and it's conquest of the world and its own demise as well.

Comment: The hat that is most comfortable to me is "expositor" but in situations like this, where I despair, I do welcome input from those who roam into more uncharted waters. I wish, though, that it were not my job to mark something as an answer which is really over my head. I think you have something there, I really do. I may decide that, given the context of a hermeneutics site, I might not be able to mark this as an answer, even if I agree. It requires intense, intimate knowledge of the history that I can't muster. I'm black/white by nature and can't fix that. But, r-e-s-p-e-c-t.

Comment: @Bach Oh boy! The Bible scientifically changes like a Chamielian's color  just to keep up with history. **THIS** is Biblical Hermeneutics? I am becoming daily amazed at the flat-earth-edness thinking of such reasoning. No longer striving to find the facts, just what-ever fits my head size?

Comment: @Ruminator I r-e-s-p-e-c-t your disregarding the comfort of any hat--whether it is the same size and color I wear also, or any other. In my old age, I have liked and woefully worn many hats that were not appropriate as to Biblical Truth.  Continue to **not trust me**, but always demand proof from Scripture.

Comment: @BillPorter  Errare humanum est.

Comment: @bill porter I appreciate you defending the bible like this, and I too usually don't engage in emending text whenever you like to suit your fancy, but sometimes the anachronism just stares you in the face, and it becomes clear that other hands were involved and that things were changed around. I think that this is one of these cases, but I might very well be wrong. Just a speculation, and I didn't even post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would understand the "king of Babylon" in Isa 14 to be the titular king as opposed to an actual king, because the last king of Babylon was not the king who conquered many cities.  More specifically,

- The king who "has been destroyed" is a prophecy about the last king of Babylon which would be either Nabonidus (556 BC - 539 BC) or his son and co-regent Beshazzar (553 BC? to 539 BC).
- The king of Babylon who "destroyed the world ... demolished the greatest cities" would be Nebuchadnezzar II (the "great") 605 BC - 562 BC.  Nebuchadnezzar conquered Charchemish, Egypt, Assyria, Phoenicia, Judea, Cilicia, and kept Jehoiachin in prison for 37 years (Jer 52:31).

Thus, here as in many places in Scripture and Hebrew idiom, the "king" stands for the kingdom.  Put another way, Babylon was personified by its king as we see in other places where Jacob is the personification of Israel, Esau is the personification of Edom, etc.

I also think that while Babylon wasted several cities, it did not make the world a wasteland; thus, Isa 14:17 is rather poetic and thus, hyperbolic.

Comment: Excellent post, Dottard. He does seem to be an amalgam and a personification of the city.

Comment: Where is the edit of your answer that shows that Isaiah 14:17 is not speaking about Titus-- chief military commander of Vespasian, who did indeed destroy many cities during their reign of terror? You say v. 17 is poetic, therefore hyperbola. This mocking occurs **after** this king’s death, and even after he has been resurrected—cast out of his grave. That has not happened yet. Jesus said that this abomination of desolation was spoken of by Daniel the prophet (Mark 13:14; Mat 24:15) Israel has not yet been given rest from their sorrow (verse 3). So where is the hyperbolic thread if not Titus?

Answer (score 0):

That king of Isaiah 14:4 KJV perfectly fits Titus. He was that King of Babylon, **diverse from**, and **extended by changes** to the little Horn of Daniel. He is the **eleventh** king of the powerful world-order of Rome, being the natural born son of, and natural heir to Vespasian--the tenth king--who was destroyed **neither in anger, nor in battle**. Daniel 11:20 demands:

> Then shall stand up in his estate a raiser of taxes in the glory of the kingdom: but within few days he shall be destroyed, **neither in anger, nor in battle**. **(My emphasis)**

That is very unusual, check out Vespasian's predecessors. They were nearly all killed or died in some manner of strife.

**MOREOVER** Titus is **also** the eighth king of that Roman world-order kingdom, beginning with Julius Caesar, according to Revelation 17:11:

> And the beast that was, and is not, even he is the eighth, and is of the seven, and goeth into perdition.

Nero was the sixth king of Revelation, and was, at the time of the prophesy to John, in the waning days of his reign as we see in Rev 17:12:

> And there are seven kings: five are fallen, and one is, and the other is not yet come; and when he cometh, he must continue a short space.

**How can He be the eleventh king of Daniel and still be the eighth king of Revelation?**

**BECAUSE** he (Titus) had to come **after** the short reign of **three rogue civil-war kings** who were not acting in the interest of the **"glory of the kingdom"**. Vespasian suceeded the three plucked-up kings, but in the glory of the kingdom because he was a dedicated Equestrian, (Dan 11:20, supra). Those three kings were **"plucked up"**--effectively eliminated--and therefore, **not counted** in Revelations tally of kings. No other Roman king or emperor fit's that set of required facts.

The historian of the day, often quoted by many of the religionists today,  was a close friend of Vespasian and Titus. In fact, he was made a member of the Royal Flavius family. No wonder,  Flavius Josephus, a Jew--who turned against the Jews and favorably toward the two men responsible for destroying the City of Jerusalem in 70 AD--did his  best to alter history and times to protect the two scoundrels--the Flauvius father and son--the two kings referred to in Daniel 11:27:

> And **both these kings'** hearts shall be to do mischief, and they shall speak lies at one table; but it shall not prosper: for yet the end shall be at the time appointed. **(My emphasis)**

The answer to the OP's question is more fully addressed, especially with respect to Isaiah 14:4, in my paper at:

https://circumspectnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/The-Days-of-These-Kings.pdf

Comment: @Ruminator Thanks for the note and the heads up. I think it is now fixed.

Comment: Neither Daniel or Revelation can, or rather should be, given short shrift.

Comment: Having waded through all this material, I conclude that Bill porter has a very pious but over-active prophetic imagination.  I am at a loss to make the connections.  What justification is there for making any interpretation other than the immediate connection that the Bible actually makes?

Comment: I agree with Dottard, there is no evidence here whatsoever that it's king Titus that is being referenced. Daniel is Daniel, and Isaiah is Isaiah, no need to conflate these two. -1.

Comment: @Dottard You conclude huh? BAM--down goes the gavel. Sounds like a very pious statement made without stating any facts which would warrant such profound **judgment**. Let's hear those facts that you adjudge as making my answer **pious.** Maybe edit your answer to prove your **judgment**, your honor.

Comment: @Bach It is Isaiah who demands that this is talking about the tribulation king in verses 1-3 of chapter 14. Only in that day will the children of Israel be able to take up this proverb that follows  verse 3. Would it not be fitting that in the very next verse to follow that Isaiah would not continue that subject matter?  You **concur** with Dottard's **judgment** on feeble facts. Every judgment must include a **findings of facts.** Where is yours?

Comment: I think we are talking about something obscure and choosing between the historic and prophetic, causing undue bifurcation (speaking from an NT/Platonic conception). I mean, is Isaiah 7:14 speaking of a young woman's human child then or about a virgin woman hosting a divinely manufactured incarnate deity?! It's a Newtonian vs Quantum matter! The NT hermeneutic, inherited from Plato via Philo, allows the NT authors to recast everything as needed for the life and times of Jesus, as the Anointed son of David. Ya just gotta be flexible!

Comment: @BillPorter, I am amused by the fact that you got 2 up votes and 2 down! You are substantial enough to be controversial. Kudos. On another subject, do I understand you to be a Dispensationalist?

Comment: @Ruminator You understand correctly.

Comment: @BillPorter Well, 69 out of 70 ain't bad! Please have a peek at my Quora Space, quora.com/q/Preterism

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy lies in the our "way of interpretating things".
Obviously this king of Babylon descriptions in Isaiah is so referring to Satan, and yet that would make it absurd since we logically would assume him as a literal historical king. But how could a literal king fell from heaven and be described as a "morning star". Taking it even symbolically as a powerful king is such a stretch and unfit metaphor. Does even a mortal emperor of the world actually think to go to Heaven and overthrow God ?

Unless, both Satan and "king of Babylon aka Lucifer" are both referring to something else, personified differently, and yet they are one and the same.

Comment: Please add further details to give evidence for your claims.

Comment: Personally, I'm of the opinion that scripture is written as it is to bewitch and perplex us more than to provide us with a solid, immediate answer. 

Trinity:...It's the question that drives us, Neo. It's the question that brought you here. You know the question, just as I did.
Neo: What is the Matrix?

Comment: Not only scripture but every ancient writings and teachings. For some reason there's some sacred inviolable laws of universe that things ought to be forbidden and remained in mystery. 
Bible was written in veiled language as many had done so in poems, monuments, arts and even now in "random books". 
Truth are reserved for true seeker, not orthodox "worshipper". Though the masses will finally reach the "One", the path shall be longer with more twists. 
Blessings and love to all beings.

Answer (score 0):

This is not satan 14:4 Isaiah say he a ruler {14:5}who conquered other nations. {14:6}As he is defeated the nations rejoice {14:7)figuratively speaking even the trees of Lebanon rejoice, for he will no longer be cutting them down for his building projects {How the Lord brought this King low, breaking his rod and septer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).